# launchctl list doesn't show StartInterval

Tags: launchd

The following is part of my `.plist` file:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>org.myorg.foo</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <!-- ... -->
  </array>
  <key>StartInterval</key>
  <integer>300</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Yet when I do a `sudo launchctl list org.myorg.foo` it prints:

```
{
    "LimitLoadToSessionType" = "System";
    "Label" = "org.myorg.foo";
    "OnDemand" = true;
    "LastExitStatus" = 0;
    "Program" = "...";
    "ProgramArguments" = (
        ...
    );
};
```

Where did the `StartInterval` go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*StartInterval* won't get printed with `(sudo) launchctl list [label]`.

Use `sudo launchctl print system/[service-name]` instead. It will be printed as *run interval*.

Depending on the domain/service target use

- `user/<uid>/[service-name]`
- `login/<asid>/[service-name]`
- `gui/<uid>/[service-name]`

instead of `system/[service-name]`

Examples:

```
host:~ user$ sudo launchctl print system/com.apple.collabd.expire | grep interval
    run interval = 600 seconds
host:~ user$ launchctl print gui/501/usr.homebrew.mxcl.autoupdate | grep interval
    run interval = 7200 seconds
```